# Java Graphics2D method for drawing an image where the pixel alpha values are used but the colour values are replaced with a given colour

Tags: java, image, swing, awt, graphics2d

I’ve been reading the API for `Graphics2D` and have seen examples of all the available composite modes (that are similar to photoshop blend modes) but I can’t see a way to draw a source image to a target buffered image In a colour that I have specified, for example my source image is a white opaque circle on a fully transparent background, how do I draw using this to a buffer so a coloured circle is drawn.

I would prefer not to construct an intermediate image for performance reasons, is this possible with the api?

EDIT: I have added an image that hopefully helps to show the operation I am trying to describe. This is a common way to draw sprites in open GL etc and I am just wondering how to use the `Graphics2D` API to do the same thing.

[image]

Comment: I don’t think this can be done without an intermediate image.  (It’s definitely possible in JavaFX, using a node’s [clip](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#clipProperty%28%29) property.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is *is* possible using the API but you have to write your own `ImageProducer` subclass similar to `FilteredImageSource` but with two input images instead of one. But because of that the end result will require more lines of code than a manual implementation and won't be any more efficient. Alternatively you can use the existing `FilteredImageSource` and write an `ImageFilter` subclass that wraps the 2nd image and does the hard work.

Poke me if you decide you want to go with any of these routes.

Answer (score 0):

Specify the location of your image in the imageName below.

```java
public class ColoredCircle extends JPanel {

   JFrame        frame     = new JFrame();

   BufferedImage buf;
   String        imageName = "F://ngc_1300_spiral.jpg";

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      new ColoredCircle().start();
   }

   int scale = 10;

   public void start() {
      try {
         buf = ImageIO.read(new File(imageName));
      }
      catch (IOException ioe) {
         ioe.printStackTrace();
      }
      setPreferredSize(
            new Dimension(buf.getWidth() / scale, buf.getHeight() / scale));
      frame.add(this);
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
      repaint();
   }

   public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
      g2d.drawImage(buf,
            0,
            0,
            buf.getWidth() / scale,
            buf.getHeight() / scale,
            null);
      g2d.dispose();

   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying but I’m looking for a solution specifically for drawing images not shapes.

Comment: I updated my answer.  Just provide the location of your image.  You may need to adjust the scale to get it fit properly.  But I still am uncertain what you want to do iwth it.

Comment: @WJS I recommend you make your answer a [mre] by using a web resource like: `ImageIO.read(new URL("http://www.digitalphotoartistry.com/rose1.jpg"));`

Comment: @wjs thanks again, but what I'm looking for is different to this, it might not even be possible with the API, but I have provided as simple an example image that I can think of to illustrate what I am trying to describe.